# WARNING: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for "external link"

Tags: jsf, mime-types, icefaces

In my icefaces web app I'm using a h:outputlink that has an image inside like this:

```
<ui:repeat var="op" value="#{usuarioBean.opcion_menu}">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="span4 menu_icon">
        <h:outputLink value="${op.link}" rendered="${op.menu_id ==6}" >
            <h:graphicImage library="img" name="${op.icono}.png" />
        </h:outputLink> 
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:repeat>
```

"${op.link}" shows an external link, this always throws a warning at my jboss console `WARNING: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for http://172.18.1.10/xyz`

I'm using jboss 7.1, icefaces, and mojarra 2.1.21

Comment: This warning is strange based on the information given so far. This warning typically only occurs on `<h:graphicImage name>`, `<h:outputStylesheet name>`, `<h:outputScript name>` and `#{resource[name]}`. Perhaps ICEfaces -which I'm not familiar with- is doing something with `<h:outputLink>` which I am not aware of. In any case, putting a debug breakpoint on `ExternalContext#getMimeType()` should give clues as to who's responsible for that call.

Comment: I already tried that and it gave me "null" (getMimeType())  also the warning only appears when the external link does not have an extension

Comment: I didn't mean to be interested in its return value (it's obviously `null`, otherwise you wouldn't get this warning), but I'm interested in **who** called it. You can see this in the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the cause for this message, but when i switched to MyFaces it disappeared. I'm on Websphere 8.5.5.11, ICEFaces **EE** 3.3, Java 1.7.

I changed from Mojarra 2.1.29 to MyFaces 2.1.19.

I was getting this message for every `<ice:outputLink>` inside `<ice:dataTable>`, tried with `<h:outputLink>` but didn't help.

```
<h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/SomeServlet" target="_blank">
    <f:param name="param1" value="#{bean.param1Value}" />
    <f:param name="param2" value="#{bean.param2Value}" />
    #{msg.click_me} 
</h:outputLink>
```

I know it's been 4 years but hope it helps someone.